# Expected number of balls to be thrown until one of $N$ urns has $\beta$ more balls than all the other urns

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics

Given $N$ urns, what is the expected number of balls that need to be thrown until one of the urns has $\beta$ more balls than all the other urns?

Comment: This is a Markov chain with infinitely many states.  I doubt there's a closed-form solution.  For specific values of $N$ and $\beta$, you could try simulation.  (I'm assuming the question means that some urn has at least $\beta$ more balls than any other urn.)

Comment: @saulspatz The states are not infinite, because we can always remove $x_m$ balls from all urns (where $x_m$ is the amount of balls of the least populated urn) and get an equivalent state. They are too many states, still.

Comment: I assume the statement is equivalent to "... until $x_1 = x_2 + \beta$  where $x_1,x_2$ are the count of balls in the most populated and second most populated urns".

Comment: @leonbloy I thought that too, at first, but why can't we have one urn with $0$ balls, and $N-1$ urns with $\alpha$ balls, $\alpha =0,1,2,\dots$?

Comment: Wouldn't this Markov chain be terminating? We may define a single absorption state.

Comment: @saulspatz Because in that case we'd have won the game earlier.

Comment: @leonbloy We must understand the game differently.  Number the urns $0$ to $N-1$.  Ball $1$ goes into urn $1$.  Ball $2$ goes into urn $2\dots$ ball $N-1$ goes into urn $N-1$.  Ball $N$ goes into urn $1$.  Ball $N+1$ goes into urn $2\dots$  ball $2N-2$ goes into urn $N-1$ and so on, forever.  The difference between the number of balls in the two most populous urns is never more than $1$, so if $\beta>1$, the game never ends.  The least populous urn never has any balls, so we can never reduce the state.  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @saulspatz Thinking it over, now I believe you're right.